# Errata List for Galois Theory (Stewart - 1st Edition)

Tags: galois-theory

I have the *first* edition (1982) of Stewart's *Galois Theory* book, and have had no luck Googling for an errata list (all I get are references to the 2nd and 3rd editions, which are apparently very different).

If anyone knows of such a list, please post a link.

Thanks.